# Could not add namespace System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit in c# wpf application in VS 2012/2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Unable to add namespace System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit in c# wpf application in VS 2012/2013

Answer (score 3):

```
You need to add a reference to WPFToolkit.dll (Not just System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit).
```

Comment: Where can I find WPFToolkit.dll?

Comment: I think that would be better if you add it through Nuget, right click on your solution project and "Manage Nuget Packages", select the Online tab and search for wpftoolkit. Install it. done. :)

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Nuget Package Manager Console Command: "Install-Package WPFToolkit" 
Linky: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFToolkit/